# Command not found for start new project

Tags: django

I am starting out with Django on my Mac, I installed Django2 and installed PyCharm

But when I try to run command from terminal to create a new project on desktop:
django-admin.py startproject name or
django-admin startproject name

then I get "command not found"

Pycharm shows my env at /Users/admin/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv

Please help

Thank you

Comment: first activate venv ie(`source ./venv/bin/activate`), then install django(`pip install django`)

Comment: should I activate directly on Mac terminal or through pycharm terminal?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the environment on the Mac, but i think the setup are almost the same.  It seems that you have not activated your environment.

I use the virtual env on an ubuntu and i have to activate the environmet before i can start creating projects and apps.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/creating-virtual-environment.html

I think this may help.  You can specify your python environment in pycharm.